# VS code SAM Debugger - Error running command "sam local start-api": Timeout token cancelled

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, sam

When I try to run the debugger in VS CODE with SAM hello world for Python, it creates the following in lunch.json

```
    {
        "type": "aws-sam",
        "request": "direct-invoke",
        "name": "API ocrSam:HelloWorldFunction",
        "invokeTarget": {
            "target": "api",
            "templatePath": "${workspaceFolder}/ocrSam/template.yaml",
            "logicalId": "HelloWorldFunction"
        },
        "api": {
            "path": "/hello",
            "httpMethod": "post",
            "payload": {
                "json": {
                    "tst": "ttt"
                }
            }
        },
        "lambda": {
            "runtime": "python3.8"
        }
    }
```

When I run it I get:

```
2023-01-06 00:43:10 [INFO]: Command: (not started) [/usr/local/bin/sam local start-api --template /tmp/aws-toolkit-vscode/vsctkDR7EPj/output/template.yaml --port 5858 --debug-port 5859 --debugger-path /home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/extensions/amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.60.0/resources/debugger --debug-args /var/lang/bin/python3.8 /tmp/lambci_debug_files/py_debug_wrapper.py --listen 0.0.0.0:5859 --wait-for-client --log-to-stderr /var/runtime/bootstrap.py]
2023-01-06 00:43:10 [ERROR]: Error running command "sam local start-api": Timeout token cancelled
```

When I copy the cmd and try to run it from CLI I get:

```
/usr/local/bin/sam local start-api --template /tmp/aws-toolkit-vscode/vsctkDR7EPj/output/template.yaml --port 5858 --debug-port 5859 --debugger-path /home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/extensions/amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.60.0/resources/debugger --debug-args /var/lang/bin/python3.8 /tmp/lambci_debug_files/py_debug_wrapper.py --listen 0.0.0.0:5859 --wait-for-client --log-to-stderr /var/runtime/bootstrap.py
```

`Error: No such option: --listen`

How can I by-pass this issue?

NOTE: this issue happened on my old pc which was dying, I bought a new mac and it doesn't happen any more, so it might be a specific problem of the pc

Comment: the `--listen` issue is because the AWS Toolkit logs don't show the exact shell quoting needed. you could try quoting everything after `--debug-args`.

more generally, the first question is, does your API take a long time to start? see also Josh's answer below.

Comment: No, the error is imediate

Comment: I got same error. My case is Windows 11 and my function takes less than 3sec, and has icnreased `aws.samcli.lambdaTimeout` to 900000 already. Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Which sam cli version do you have installed and which OS are you using?

Can you try increasing the `aws.samcli.lambdaTimeout` setting in the VSCode settings to something like 90000 (1.5 minutes) to see if the default timeout is too low